# NUT upsrw ERR READONLY

Tags: ups, nut

I am using NUT to shutdown the ups powering my CentOS 6 server but it has a 30 second delay when executing the shutdown.

When I run

```
upsc
```

I can see that the 30 seconds is controlled by the variable

```
ups.delay.shutdown: 30
```

However when I try to change it using

```
upsrw -u upsmon -p upsmon -s ups.delay.shutdown=0 mecer
```

Then I get the following error

```
ERR READONLY
```

Why is this? If removing those 30 seconds is not possible then is it possible to just make the ups power off after 10min?

Comment: Maybe this will help you. http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/nut-upsuser/2013-December/008747.html